# Output of php script needs to be save in $content

Tags: php, mysql

How do I need to adjust the below php if the output of the php-script needs to be saved in $content?

```
<?php

//db verbindung
mysql_connect("Hostname", "Username", "Password");
mysql_select_db("Database Name");
//db abfrage
$query = "SELECT 
    YEAR(datetime) AS dy, 
    MONTH(datetime) -1 AS dm, 
    DAY(datetime) AS dd, 
    HOUR(datetime) AS th, 
    MINUTE(datetime) AS tm, 
    temp, 
    hum, 
    pressure 
    FROM wettertabelle 
    WHERE DATE(datetime) = '2013-11-25' 
    ORDER BY datetime
";
// NEU: Variable definieren
$zeilenzaehler = 1;
//ausgabe der zeilen
$result = mysql_query($query)
        OR die("Error: $query <br>" . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
// echo 
    if ($zeilenzaehler != 1) {
        echo ",";
    }
    echo "{date: new Date(" . $row['dy'] . "," . $row['dm'] . "," . $row['dd'] . "," . $row['th'] . "," . $row ['tm'] . "),t:" . $row['temp'] . ",h:" . $row['hum'] . ",p:" . $row['pressure'] . "}";
//Variable jetzt auf 2
    $zeilenzaehler = 2;
};
?>
```

What is working is e.g.:

```
<?php
$content = This is the output!!
?>
```

or

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo 'This is the output!!';   
$content=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

How would I need to adjust the above script to get it into the following output structure:

```
<?php
class user_klasse
{
function ausgabe()
{
return 'This test is generated by php.';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You already have working things then ? What do you want ?

Comment: Why are you posting that as a question, instead of just executing it and use the version that works. (hint: only one of the posted solutions would work…)

Comment: I use Typo3 and Typo3 requires the php to be saved in $content! At least now it's working! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have two `echo` statements, change them to save the value in your variable. No need for output buffering for something so small.

```
if ($zeilenzaehler != 1)
{
  $content.= ",";    // instead of echo, and same for the one below
}
$content.= "{date: new Date(".$row['dy'].",".$row['dm'].",".$row['dd'].",".$row['th'].",".$row ['tm']."),t:".$row['temp'].",h:".$row['hum'].",p:".$row['pressure']."}";
```

At the end you can just do

```
echo $content;
```